# rake db:create ignores database.yml content

Tags: postgresql, rake, grape-api, napa

I am using [Napa](https://github.com/bellycard/napa) framework.

```
rake db:create
```

gives me the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Investigating the problem I found that rake tries to create database using my system user rather than the one specified within database.yml
Removing database.yml gives 'file not found', so it looks like it is read properly.

My database.yml content:

```
defaults: &defaults
  encoding: unicode
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: pushnote
  password: secret123

production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: pushnote_production

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: pushnote_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: pushnote_test

staging:
  <<: *defaults
  database: pushnote_production
```

Anyone can help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the newest Napa code from git instead of relaying on this what's inside the gem :)

For example, in your Gemfile add this:

```
gem 'napa', :git => 'https://github.com/bellycard/napa.git'
```